# If I use <ErrorBoundary>, will Error.cshtml ever be displayed?

Tags: blazor, blazor-server-side

When Visual Studio creates the basic Blazor server app, it includes an Error.cshtml file. As I understand it, this is displayed if there's an unhandled exception when rendering.

But if in MainLayout.razor I have:

```
<ErrorBoundary>
    <ChildContent>
        <!-- ... -->
    </ChildContent>
    <ErrorContent Context="error">
        <!-- ... -->
    </ErrorContent>
</ErrorBoundary>
```

Will `Error.cshtml` ever be displayed? Or does the `<ErrorContent>` now handle every case of where previously `Error.cshtml` was displayed.

I ask because I have it set up this way and I have never had the Error page come up. So I think it's unused if `<ErrorBoundary>` is defined. But I worry that I just haven't hit an exception in the circumstances where it will display.

Comment: In this case, I think just doing it is the easiest way to find out.

Comment: @Bennyboy1973 I added a postscript to my question. I am using `<ErrorBoundary>` - my worry is there is a use case where Error.cshtml is displayed and I just haven't hit it - yet.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The `<ErrorBoundary>` component is a new feature in .NET 6 that allows you to handle unhandled exceptions in your Blazor components and display custom error content. The `Error.cshtml` file is the default error page for ASP.NET Core apps that is displayed when an unhandled exception occurs outside of the Blazor components, such as in middleware, controllers, or Razor pages².

If you use the `<ErrorBoundary>` component in your `MainLayout.razor` file, it will catch any unhandled exceptions that occur within the child components and render the `<ErrorContent>` instead of the default yellow bar¹. However, this does not mean that the `Error.cshtml` file is never used. There are some scenarios where the  component cannot handle the exceptions, such as:

- When the exception occurs during the initial rendering of the app, before the `<ErrorBoundary>` component is rendered¹.
- When the exception occurs in the `<ErrorBoundary>` component itself or in its parameters¹.
- When the exception occurs in a component that is not a child of the `<ErrorBoundary>` component, such as a top-level component in the `App.razor` file.
- When the exception occurs outside of the Blazor components, such as in middleware, controllers, or Razor pages².

In these cases, the Error.cshtml file will be displayed instead of the `<ErrorBoundary>` component. Therefore, you should not remove the `Error.cshtml` file from your app, as it is still useful for handling errors that the `<ErrorBoundary>` component cannot handle.

I hope this answers your question. If you want to learn more about the `<ErrorBoundary>` component and how to use it, you can check out the following resources:

(1) Handle errors in ASP.NET Core Blazor apps | Microsoft Learn. https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/blazor/fundamentals/handle-errors?view=aspnetcore-7.0.
(2) Handle errors in ASP.NET Core Blazor apps - GitHub. https://github.com/dotnet/AspNetCore.Docs/blob/main/aspnetcore/blazor/fundamentals/handle-errors.md.